# APEX Division with Decimal

Tags: apex

I declare the variable as Decimal and use division operator / but I always get round numbers
on my VS CODE.

For example :

```
Decimal age = 225/12;
```

gives the output `18`

Why?

Answer (score 3):

You are performing division on `Integer` values, so the result is an `Integer` before you assign it to a `Decimal` variable. This behavior is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_rules_of_conversion.htm):

> Loss of Fractions in Divisions

> When dividing numeric `Integer` or `Long` values, the fractional portion of the result, if any, is removed before performing any implicit conversions to a `Double` or `Decimal`. For example, `Double d = 5/3`; returns `1.0` because the actual result (`1.666...`) is an `Integer` and is rounded to `1` before being implicitly converted to a `Double`. To preserve the fractional value, ensure that you are using `Double` or `Decimal` numeric values in the division. For example, `Double d = 5.0/3.0`; returns `1.6666666666666667` because `5.0` and `3.0` represent `Double` values, which results in the quotient being a `Double` as well and no fractional value is lost.

Express your values as a `Double` or assign them to a `Decimal` before performing division to avoid this truncation behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot David

Comment: Much Appreciated